# SqlAlchemy db.metadata.create_all - does not create table when __bind_key__ has been specified?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I create a class (Table), and I specify the **bind_key** = "bindingname" the table is not created using this method:

db.metadata.create_all(db.engines["bindingname"])

however, when I remove the **bind_key** property from the table class, the table is indeed created, however it will get created in all my bindings ...

how can i specify **bind_key** in a class table definition and then ensure that the table is created only in the specified database?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, managed to get it working like this.

Example of class

```
from models.Models import db

class V3_Output_Binned(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "output_v3"
    __tablename__ = "V3_Output_Bin"
```

Example of how and where to create the missing tables, I need to do this since there is one database (binding) that I do not want to have table schemas auto created.

db.init_app(app)

```
@app.before_first_request 
def create_table():
    #db.create_all()
    with app.app_context():
       
        db.create_all(bind_key="default")
        db.create_all(bind_key="output")
        db.create_all(bind_key="output_v3")
```

If you need more information - having the same issue, let me know and I will give advice.